# Trouble Installing PyAudio in Pycharm in windows 10

Tags: python, installation, pyaudio

I Am Trying To Install PyAudio Package in Pycharm, but it is not being installed and this error is shown:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Have tried On Pycharm, running on Windows 10

Command Output:

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio: started
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\iamsu\PycharmProjects\Casper\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\iamsu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\iamsu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lvejcfmx\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\iamsu\PycharmProjects\Casper\venv\include\site\python3.7\PyAudio:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\iamsu\PycharmProjects\Casper\venv\include -IC:\Users\iamsu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\iamsu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\iamsu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    c:\users\iamsu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): note: command-line arguments:  see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------

Command "C:\Users\iamsu\PycharmProjects\Casper\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\iamsu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\iamsu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lvejcfmx\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\iamsu\PycharmProjects\Casper\venv\include\site\python3.7\PyAudio" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\iamsu\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\PyAudio\
```

Comment: Check if this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638663/unable-to-install-pyaudio-package/57638744#57638744

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue which was solved by executing below commands.

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install C++ Build Tools to download this package. Alternatively, you can download and install Visual Studio.

Comment: Already installed... After Installation of c++ Build tools , its showing this type of error !!

Comment: Then maybe it's the python version you are using. I think pyAudio works for python_version<=3.6

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in PyCharm is probably caused because you are not using the right Python Interpreter. Most Users install first Python then PyCharm, without knowing that PyCharm install another Python Installation with it together. This should be the same issue with you because your PyCharm tries to use the build.py in the Visual Studio Directory. So here is what you have to check:

1. On CMD/Terminal write "pip install pyaudio". If you can't install on Windows with CMD install pip via: [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. Check where your python Path is. You can do this on CMD/Terminal with the command "*pip -V*" this will show you the **Path + Version of pip!**. Now becarefull not to notice the pip Path! You have to **Notice your Path to the Python Directory which is 2 Directory over the pip Folder!** For example you will get an output like: "./python3/dist-packages/pip"
3. Check your Base interpreter. Is it the same Python Path from Step 2? If not change your Base interpreter to the python Path. Try to install it now.
4. If its still not working just Create a new Project with the Base Interpreter using the python installation Path from Step 2 and activate the checkbox "***Inherit global site-packages***".

Answer (score 0):

**(Maybe your problem is already solved. My answer may will help for new guys who will face the same problem)
PyAudio depends on PortAudio, which may not be installed on your system. You can try installing PortAudio manually first and then install PyAudio.
if you are using Python 3.9 on Windows 10 64-bit, download the file named PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl and install it using the following command:

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```